# Update only "changed values" for an existing entity

Tags: spring

I am creating a rest API to update my entity with the new changes, but my entity is having like 20 attributs and i don't think it's a good way to just put multiple sets and "if" conditions to not set old values with NULL.

I want to know if there is a way in spring that can update the whole entity without changing the old unchanged values to null instead of putting a lot of Setters (~20 in my case).